# Both branches are behind each other. How do I merge the two branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push, git-pull, bitbucket-server

The branches in consideration are in the published repository server.

Consider a branch A containing a set of commits from which branch B is created.
Extra commits are added to the branch B (let's say they are in active development)
At this point a commit is added to Branch A.

Now Branch A is behind Branch B by lets say 10 commits and Branch B is behind branch A by a single commit.

Now these two branches cannot be merged as they are both behind each other by atleast a single commit.
In order to keep everything in sync, how do I merge branch A and B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can merge both branches with `git merge`. I don't recommend using `git rebase` on this case since you said both branches have already been published to the repository server.

I've created the following situation (described on your post):

```
$ git co A
$ git lg --all
* 4df39d7 - (HEAD, A) 2nd commit on A (9 seconds ago)
| * f1f57d8 - (B) 1st commit on B (39 seconds ago)
|/
* 8228446 - (master) . (2 minutes ago)

$ git co B
$ git lg --all
* 4df39d7 - (A) 2nd commit on A (2 minutes ago)
| * f1f57d8 - (HEAD, B) 1st commit on B (3 minutes ago)
|/
* 8228446 - (master) . (4 minutes ago)
```

So assuming we're in branch `B` you can merge `A` by doing: `git merge A`

Which turns the history into this:

```
$ git merge A
$ git lg --all
*   5517453 - (HEAD, B) Merge branch 'A' into B (2 minutes ago)
|\
| * 4df39d7 - (A) 2nd commit on A (5 minutes ago)
* | f1f57d8 - 1st commit on B (6 minutes ago)
|/
* 8228446 - (master) . (7 minutes ago)
```

Additional note:

The `git lg` and `git co` are [aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) that I've created in order to make it easier to work with the git command line. They stand for (as configured on my `.gitconfig`):

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
co = checkout
```

Comment: Good answer (+1), but please refrain from using aliases without specifying what they stand for; a newcomer to Git might get confused by `git co`, `git lg`, etc.

Comment: @Jubobs good idea. I'm updating the answer with the definitions of each alias.